# Django forms: how to use a switch case ChoiceField / choises using request.session value?

Tags: python, django, forms

I have 2 linked models for thesaurus with labels in English and French

I have a 2 class methods (options_list_eng and options_list_fra) that return a list of labels based on code pass in parameters: one that returns french labels and the other return English labels

I also have a `request.session['language']` that catch the browser language of the user

I want to use theses methods to set choices attributes in my form depending on the language (value in `request.session.get('language')`)

I try use something like that but it do not works

```
if self.language == 'en':
    TYPES = Thesaurus.options_list_eng(1)
else:
    TYPES = Thesaurus.options_list_fra(1)
```

below my current code that runs well but does not allow french/english translation of choices

**forms.py**

```
class RandomisationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        self.language = request.session.get('language')
        super(RandomisationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

TYPES = Thesaurus.options_list_eng(1)
ran_pro = forms.ChoiceField(label = _("Type"), widget=forms.Select, choices=TYPES)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define field in form's `__init__` method like this:

```
class RandomisationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RandomisationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.request = request
        self.language = request.session.get('language')
        if self.language == 'en':
            TYPES = Thesaurus.options_list_eng(1)
        else:
            TYPES = Thesaurus.options_list_fra(1)

        self.fields["ran_pro"] = forms.ChoiceField(label = _("Type"), widget=forms.Select, choices=TYPES)
```

Comment: I have try that but get the error: NameError: name 'TYPES' is not defined

Comment: No sorry, it works... but I did not construct my form like that

Comment: first I simply define each field outside the constructor like that: ran_pro = forms.ChoiceField(label = _("Type"), widget=forms.Select, choices=TYPES)

Comment: What do you mean by `not construct my form like that`?

Comment: I did not use self.fields["ran_pro"] in constructor but directly ran_pro = outside... maybe it is not the right way to do it?

Comment: Well, you can define all other fields as in you initial code. You need this hack inside init only for `ran_pro` field. Otherwise you cannot get value inside request.session. Since code outside of init method running when project is starting and not when request is passed to the server.

Comment: but I can also define all my fields in init method, right?

Comment: Sure it's up to you.